Raspberry Pi Imager throws initializesecuritycontext Error - while writing OS to the SD card for Raspberry Pi 5 device
Trying to install Raspberry Pi OS into the SD card using Raspberry Pi Imager tool. I've verified the requirements of the memory, SD card is fully formatted and is in a working condition. However, upon selecting the Device, OS and storage - clicking on Next, throws the below error:
"Error downloading: schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092013) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline"
Tried with multiple SD cards, getting the same error.
FYI, I'm trying to install OS for Raspberry Pi 5 (latest model) and selecting the 64-bit OS, also tried other OS options like 32-bit, lite versions etc.,
Below is the screenshot.


On which OS do you run the imager? Try the latest version of the imager.

did you blank out the "Server IP" in that error message? Because other than having no IP shown there, it looks similar to this rpi-imager issue which seems to have been caused by having a probably poorly configured VPN on the system trying to user the imager program

Oh, wait, I see you found that issue, and posted a "me too" comment on it at about the same time as you posted this question - presumably AFTER

@JaromandaX - I've edited the image 'not to show ip' !!

Thanks @JaromandaX, the issue got resolved with VPN configurations!!

As suggested by Jaromanda X in the post comments, I've found the related issue here - https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-imager/issues/776.
Following the suggestions, reconfiguring the VPN and removing the restrictions on the VPN settings and running the imager fixed the issue!!
Thanks @Jaromanda X
